# WPF TreeView (hierarchicaldatatemplate ) with 2 tables

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I have 2 db tables:

- ProductGroup(GroupID, GroupName, ...)
- Product(ProductID, ProductName, GroupID, ...)

Now I want to display the ProductGroup and the Product Table in a TreeView.

I am using an Entity Model and I dont now how to bind 2 Tables to 1 TreeView.

I am looking forward to some answers! THX

Comment: 1) http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/  
2) have you seen code sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx

Comment: I visited this link more than once but i didnt get it. Do i need to create a class for each table? Is there no better way to bind it directly without extra classes?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "extra classes"? You've tagged your question with `entity-framework` tag. So, you have these classes already, don't you?

Comment: no i dont have the classes yet ;) isnt there another way for the treeview to solve the problem?

Comment: It's a very, very strange way - to work with ORM, which Entity Framework is, without "extra" classes. This is what EF is intended for - **map** your tables to **objects**.

Comment: ok thx! Made the classes... Do i have to create for every ProductGroup a List of Products ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string TextFields=string.Empty;
    private string TagFields=string.Empty;
    public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
FillTree();
}


void FillTree()
{
DataSet mds = new DataSet();
DataSet dds = new DataSet();
string ssql;
TextFields = "GroupName"; 
TagFields = "GroupID"; 
this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
ssql = "select GroupID, GroupName from productgroups ";
mds =  DB.GetInstance.GetDataSet( ssql);
if(mds!=null)
   insert1LevelNodes(null,mds.Tables[0]);
ssql="select ProductID, ProductName, GroupID from products";
dds =  GetDataSet(ssql);
if(dds!=null)
{
    for(short i = 0;i<this.treeView1.Nodes.Count;i++)
    {   
        TextFields = "ProductName";
        TagFields = "ProductID";
        insert1LevelNodes(this.treeView1.Nodes[i],dds.Tables[0] );

    }
}
dds.Clear();
dds.Dispose();
}


void insert1LevelNodes(TreeNode parentNode, DataTable dt)
{
    string sNodeText = "";
    string sNodeTag = "";
    string[] aTexts = this.TextFields.Split(',');
    string[] aTags = this.TagFields.Split(',');
    for(int i=0; i< dt.Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        sNodeText = "";
        sNodeTag = "";
        for(int k=0;k<dt.Columns.Count;k++)
        {
            for(short j=0;j<aTexts.Length;j++)
                if(aTexts[j].Equals(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName))
                    sNodeText+=dt.Rows[i][k].ToString() + ":";
            for(short j=0;j<aTags.Length;j++)
                if(aTags[j].Equals(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName))
                    sNodeTag+=dt.Rows[i][k].ToString() + ",";
        }
        if(sNodeText.Length>0) sNodeText = sNodeText.TrimEnd(':');
        if(sNodeTag.Length>0) sNodeTag = sNodeTag.TrimEnd(',');

        if(sNodeText==string.Empty) return;
        TreeNode newNode=new TreeNode(sNodeText);
        newNode.Tag = sNodeTag;
        if(parentNode==null)
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        else
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
    }
}

DataSet GetDataSet(string ssql)
{
/// Your function to get Dataset from your Database
}
}
```

Comment: The question about WPF, not WinForms.